# Am I using the right resistors with these MOSFETs for an ESP8266 controlled LED strip?

Tags: led, mosfet, resistors, impedance, esp8266

this is my first question here. I hope I don't mess it up.

I made a WiFi controlled LED strip about a year ago. The LED strip is one of the "dumb" (no individual pixel control) 12V ones and I used a Wemos Mini to control it. Now, I want to make a another one, but I can't remember why I chose the resistor values I did. Does the following look right?

[image: Wiring Mock-up for WiFi LED Strip]

The MOSFETs are [40T03GP](https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/40T03GP.html). I tried googling, but I can't find a setup similar to mine to compare it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using mosfets you can get rid of those 220ohm resistors. And if you are sure that your ESP outputs always are going to have a determinated logic state (0 or 1) even you can delete the 10k pulldown resistors. Remember that fet transistors does not require current but voltage

Comment: Thanks. The outputs are going to be analog write signals (between 0 and 1020) depending on the color desired, so I still need them right?

Comment: does that outputs have a DAC? or the analog write is a PWM signal?

Comment: I'm not really sure. In my code I am using analogWrite, but after a little googling, it looks like the Mini only has one analog-in pin, and no analog-outs (really not sure about this though). So, I think the analogWrite function might actually be sending a PWM signal.

Comment: tried it again without all the resistors. Everything works. Cheers